# Triage spam audit that doesn’t appear to be spam

Tags: support, disputed-review-audits

I recently got this [triage audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/34820607) and reading the question I don't see any signs of spam. I almost submitted `Looks Ok` until I saw the comment saying it was spam. I looked at the linked meta post and saw the question poster had a network-wide suspension and then flagged as spam.

I think this audit should be removed and other similar ones if there are since there is no sign it is spam by reading the post.

[image: Image of the question]

Comment: The user that posted received a suspension for over two centuries (274 years), so that’s somewhat of a red flag. Not sure what exactly happened with that particular post, but I’d guess maybe a mod deleted it as R/A causing it to become eligible to be an audit?

Comment: @cocomac Correct but I dont look at a user's profile while reviewing unless I have a reason to like the comment here. Besides we don't spam flag posts made by users that have a spammy profile

Comment: I've made it no longer eligible to be an audit. [That whole situation](/q/418569) is a bit of a mess... I'll take a look to see if there are any other confusing audits connected there, but I can't guarantee more posts like this won't be chosen as audits for various reasons.

Comment: "*since there is no sign it is spam by reading the post.*" => I don't completely agree, maybe there is no visible/obvious Spam-Link in the Post, but the wording really sounds like "I have this fake problem" (and "my Post has a *secret agenda*, like I will later silently add a Spam-Link, or this is part of a promo-campaign"...).

Comment: How on earth is that question "looks ok"? It contains no information to diagnose their actual problem, so it most certainly isn't "looks ok".  Let's disregard the fact it's actually a spam seed.

Comment: Yep. When a question says, "I have made several attempts" Dodoes not proceed to describe at least some of the attempts, the question's almost assuredly not going to be useful.

Comment: @chivracq Agreed but I dont think non-obvious spam seeds should be audits

Comment: @ Ethan, yep agreed, but this one is definitely a very clear "fake Post", with like I mentioned earlier a *secret agenda* in it, part of a promo-campaign or voting-ring, or the User will add some Spam-Link "later on"... // I went checking on all Dots/Commas, hovering on those when I first checked the Post, pretty convinced I would find some "hidden" Spam-Link, ah-ah...!